# concurrency in a single Processor instance and concurrentConsumers

Tags: java, apache-camel

If I have a code like this:

```
Processor myProcessor = new MyProcessor();
CamelContext cContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
cContext.addComponent("jms", new MyJmsComponent());
cContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("jms://my-jms-endpoint?concurrentConsumers=5").process(myProcessor);
        }
    });
```

Is this code concurrent? I assume the messages are consumed concurrently by competing consumers, but what happens in the myProcessor instance? Is it cloned automagically by Camel? Or is myProcessor assumed to be thread safe and messages are processed concurrently by the single instance? Or are the messages synchronized to access the myProcessor sequentially in this snippet? If the latter is the case, how do I achieve concurrency?

Comment: If the camel Route consume multiple message at the same time the Processor is assumed to be thread safe. If you feel like that would impact too much on performance maybe you can create a pool of processors

Comment: Thanks Anthony. If Processor is assumed to be thread safe, how would the performance benefit by creating a pool of processors?

Comment: A thread safe class often embed some locking mechanism. Under certain circumstances it can helps to use a pool of worker. Not all worker can benefit (or even work) with pool, it all depend on what the processor does and what is the things that needs to be thread safe

Comment: Ok, so I understand the potential performance impact would come only from some specific implementation of the Processor. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: No problem ;) glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the camel Route consume multiple message at the same time the `Processor` is assumed to be thread safe, because multiple consumer may use it at the same time.

If you feel like that would impact too much on performance (due to possible locking mechanism) maybe you can create a pool of processors. Although not all worker can benefit (or even work) with pool, it all depend on what the processor does and what is the things that needs to be thread safed.